# Why does this differential equation not rely on time for the constants?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to solve a differential equation I found online and the problem is as follows

> A population of insects in a region will grow at a rate that is
>   proportional to their current population. In the absence of any
>   outside factors the population will triple in two weeks time. On any
>   given day there is a net migration into the area of 15 insects and 16
>   are eaten by the local bird population and 7 die of natural causes. If
>   there are initially 100 insects in the area will the population
>   survive? If not, when do they die out?

The differential equation of the solution appears to be
$dP/dt = (rP+15)-(16+7) = rP-8$

While what I got was close, my equation relied on time for the daily increase/decrease being $dP/dt = rP-8t$.

My logic for this is that these are factors that take place daily, rather than just a set amount. Why is this wrong?

Comment: Time is already in days, so subtracting 8 means you remove 8 each day. 8t is what comes from integrating that term.

Comment: @Ian I think I understand in that case, thank you! I didn't consider it when I integrated.